# Query to use group by in inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have Two tables

Table 1

```
|ID | totalamount |          
|100| 1000        |          
|101| 500         |
```

Table 2

```
|ID  | Individualamount|
|100 | 500             |
|100 | 300             |
|100 | 100             |
|101 | 200             |
|101 | 300             |
```

I Need a result which shows

```
|ID |TotalAmount|sum(Individualamount)|difference(TA-IA)|%of diff|
|100|1000       |900                  |100              |10      |
|101|500        |500                  |0                |0       |
```

Comment: Where is your query?

Comment: what is % of diff ??

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.TotalAmount
      , Sum(t2.IndividualAmount) As IndividualSum
      , t1.TotalAmount-Sum(t2.IndividualAmount) As Difference
      , (100*t1.TotalAmount-Sum(t2.IndividualAmount))/t1.TotalAmount As Percent
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.TotalAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
      A.ID[ID],
      TotalAmount,
      SUM(Individualamount),
      TotalAmount-SUM(Individualamount)[difference(TA-IA)],
      CASE WHEN TotalAmount-SUM(Individualamount)='0' THEN 0 ELSE (TotalAmount/TotalAmount-SUM(Individualamount))*100 END [%of diff]
FROM Table1 A INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.ID=B.ID
GROUP BY A.ID,TotalAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(id int,totalamount numeric(10,2))
insert into #TEMP values(100,1000)
insert into #TEMP values(101,500)

CREATE TABLE #TEMP1(id int,individualamount numeric(10,2))
insert into #TEMP1 values(100,500)
insert into #TEMP1 values(100,300)
insert into #TEMP1 values(100,100)
insert into #TEMP1 values(101,200)
insert into #TEMP1 values(101,300)



select t.id,t.totalamount TA,sum(t1.individualamount) IA,t.totalamount-sum(t1.individualamount) TA_IA,((t.totalamount-sum(t1.individualamount))/t.totalamount)*100 Percentage from #TEMP t inner join #TEMP1 t1 on t.id=t1.id
group by t.id,t.totalamount

drop table #TEMP
drop table #TEMP1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  do it by applying join

```
SELECT   table1.ID,
         table1.totatlAmount),
         sum(table2.IndividualAmount),
         (table2.totatlAmount - SUM(IndividualAmount)) AS difference(TA-IA),
(100*t1.TotalAmount-Sum(t2.IndividualAmount))/t1.TotalAmount As %of diff
    FROM     table1 INNER JOIN
             table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
    GROUP BY table1.ID,
             table1.TotalAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write as:

```
-- Now you can do the calculations the way you want:
select Id, 
       totalamount,
       [sum(Individualamount)],
       totalamount - [sum(Individualamount)] as [difference(TA-IA)]
from (
-- First get core data to be used for other columns 
SELECT  T1.Id,
        T1.totalamount AS totalamount,
        SUM(T2.Individualamount) AS [sum(Individualamount)]
FROM @Tab1 T1
JOIN @Tab2 T2 ON T1.Id= T2.Id 
GROUP BY T1.Id, T1.totalamount ) as T
```